# Update XsltListViewWebPart.ViewGuid Property on Page Load

Tags: 2013, web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

I have a web part page with two `XsltListViewWebPart` web parts on it. Both are the same web parts pointing to the same Tasks list.

I'm trying to update the view of both web parts and have the below code, but it doesn't have any affect.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web)
    {
        SPLimitedWebPartManager manager = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(this.Page.Request.Url.ToString(), System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        SPLimitedWebPartCollection webPartColl = manager.WebParts;

        for (int i = 0; i < webPartColl.Count; i++)
        {
            if (webPartColl[i].GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.XsltListViewWebPart))
            {
                XsltListViewWebPart webpart = (XsltListViewWebPart)webPartColl[i];
                webpart.ViewGuid = "{BF9F9D23-F17A-41B6-80AC-498377347D60}";
                manager.SaveChanges(webpart);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:

It seems `manager.WebParts` is returning nothing, even though there are web parts on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this: web.GetLimitedWebPartManager
be something like page.GetLimitedWebPartManager?

In my logice there are no webparts on the web object, but they should be on the page object.

Comment: There is definitely a `GetLimitedWebPartManager` property for the SPWeb class; it takes the URL to the relevant page as one of its parameters.

Comment: Ok, I just checked some code I have on how I did it and I used the page object. Otherwise I wouldn't know why it's empty.

Comment: OK I'll try your method and see if it's still empty.